# Bandwidth Monitoring Using google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, networking, bandwidth

i was trying to log the amount of bandwidth i was consuming by making an extension for google chrome. So while googling i came across this command specific to google chrome:

chrome://net-internals/#bandwidth

it basically does what i wanted all along, but it gives readings in kilobytes and i want to extract this convert this to either megabytes/ gigabytes and show this to the user in a more descriptive and convenient way. i googled but i wasn't able to find a way to extract this information. Is there a way to extract this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way to do it. Chrome stores log files, just had to look for it.